# Parent access child prototype function

Tags: javascript

I was learning OOP Js from the following example. It's all good and cool, i was just wondering if it's possible to access **Student**'s prototype method **sayGoodBye**, i understand this can be achieve use abstract method in PHP, but just wondering is there a way to do this in JS OOP. Thanks

I may not been very clear, the code example is perfect just wondering, if can do

```
Person.prototype.walk = function(){
      //Goog bye is the method in Student.
      this.sayGoodBye();
};
```

The working code.

```
function Person(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
}

Person.prototype.walk = function(){
  alert("I am walking!");
};
Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName);
};

function Student(firstName, subject) {
  Person.call(this, firstName);

  this.subject = subject;
};

Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // See note below

Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  alert("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + ". I'm studying " + this.subject + ".");
};

Student.prototype.sayGoodBye = function(){
  alert("Goodbye!");
};

var student1 = new Student("Janet", "Applied Physics");
student1.sayHello();   // "Hello, I'm Janet. I'm studying Applied Physics."
student1.walk();       // "I am walking!"
student1.sayGoodBye(); // "Goodbye!"

alert(student1 instanceof Person);  // true 
alert(student1 instanceof Student); // true
```

Comment: Aren't you already accessing (and calling) the `sayGoodBye` method in your code successfully? I don't really understand what your problem is, the code looks perfect. *Where* do you need to access the method?

Comment: @bergi i have update the question, i mean access child function within parent's function, if i want to call goodbye() within walk()

Comment: Sure, you can just call it there (it will on all `Student` instances, not on `Parent` ones). However, you've got a spelling mistake, the method is named `.sayGoodBye()` not `.goodbye()`.

Comment: So, any problems left?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, as long as each "sub class" of *Person* has a *sayGoodBye* method, though you might put a default method on *Person.prototype*.

Comment: Given the odd coupling you've created now it would make sense to also have `sayGoodBye` on the `Person` prototype, perhaps as an empty shell function.

Comment: @Jack Thanks that clear my question. should place in the answer i will tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike PHP, JavaScript doesn't have something like abstract methods in the language itself; if you want to force an implementation in objects that extend the prototype, you could write something like:

```
Person.prototype.sayGoodbye = function() {
    throw "You must implement me!";
};
```